# "customSearch must return a boolean" (despite I'm returning one)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to overload a component of mui datatable package, named `customSearch`

Basically, I'm trying to do a search in an endpoint when searching in a table.
Everything is working fine, but the browser console is throwing me this error, "customSearch must return a boolean", when I'm already returning one.
What could be the problem? Anything related to the function being async?
Am I missing any return?

```
customSearch: async (searchQuery) => {
        let isFound = false;
        if (searchQuery.length > 2 && enterPressed && enterLocked === false) {
          const res = await apiFetch('GET', { endPoint: `patients/?name=${searchQuery}` });
          const resultado = res.data;
          if (resultado.length !== 1) {
            resultado.forEach((dataRes, index) => {
              dataRes.sync = true;
              resultado[index] = dataRes;
            });
            isFound = true;
          }
          this.setState({
            data: parsePatientsList(resultado, literals.active),
            itemsLoaded: itemsLoaded + resultado.length,
            pagesLoaded: pagesLoaded + Math.floor(resultado.length / 10) + 1,
            patientList: [...patientList, ...data],
            enterPressed: false,
            enterLocked: true,
          });
          return isFound;
        }
        return isFound;
      },
```

Comment: This isn't valid JS. You are missing something in your function declaration from what we can see here.

Comment: `customSearch` is an async function, hence its return type is `Promise<boolean>`

Comment: Since this is a async function, are you calling the function like `const result = await customSearch(searchQuery)`

Comment: I'm expecting a `let, const, function` declaration. What more is left out? How is the function called?

Comment: I suggest you to add `//@ts-check` at the top of the file to get type hints in your IDE

Comment: @Joel this is inside some components of the mui datatable I'm overloading / customizing. So it acts like a function despite the declaration not being complete (I have some others components and will be so much code)

Comment: @pavi2410 is there any way to return it only when the prmise is fulfilled then?

Comment: @kiranvj I'm not explictly calling it because I'm passing it to the options of the mui datatable overloading the search component (which is probably not async), is there any wayt to fix this without calling it with an await, but being async?

Comment: Nope.  If you need the value to be returned to the caller, async/await.  If you don't mind putting your code that uses the value inside a callback, promise.then.

Comment: @JuanFranciscoRuiz since the `customSearch` function is "sync", you have to ditch async-based fetch API to use XMLHttpRequest. But that would offer a suboptimal experience.

Comment: You should file a feature request to the library

Comment: @pavi2410 thanks, should probably do that